# CSS3 Fade-In Delay?

Tags: css, animation

I'm fading in two objects on a very simple page. First the logo, then the text. Why is the animation on the text not delaying with this code? The other one works flawlessly, but it doesn't have any delay.

```
    .centralimg {
        background-image: url(logo.png);
        background-size: 576px 173px;
        width: 576px;
        height: 173px;
        animation: fadein 1200ms;
        -moz-animation: fadein 1200ms; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-animation: fadein 1200ms; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-animation: fadein 1200ms; /* Opera */
                }
    .centraltext {
        color: rgb(147, 145, 147);
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
        margin-top: 25px;
        animation: fadein 1200ms;
        animation-delay: 3s;
        -moz-animation: fadein 1200ms; /* Firefox */
        -moz-animation-delay:3s;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 1200ms; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -webkit-animation-delay:3s;
        -o-animation: fadein 3200ms; /* Opera */
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle we can play around with?

Comment: For us to see the whole picture here, and to able to give a proper answer, we need the missing CSS and HTML to reproduces the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you must add some property to the `.centraltext`, because it should not be visible until the animation is applied (`opacity: 0` in JSFiddle example).

And also add the property animation-fill-mode to preserve the style of the last frame.

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leusrox/r98r925d/)

```
.centraltext {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and is better than hacking together key-frames to get the delay working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It will delay two seconds, then start the animation. It can be useful.

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-delay: 2s;
```